# iterating through listView order

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i'm iterating through items in listView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ld.Items.Count; i++)
{
   ld.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text = (i+1).ToString();
}
```

it seems it iterates in the same order as items were added to listView. What i need is to iterate through items in order they are displayed (after sorting for example).

Comment: Are you sure? I've tried it and looks like after sorting the loop should be in the order of sorting (not in the order of adding the items)

Comment: Are the items from a databound list or added manually?

Comment: ld.Items.Add(viewItem); // so i guess it's manually